Class decoder: For unbatched 2-D input, hx and cx should also be 2-D but got (3-D, 3-D) tensors
The scenario: I don’t want to use embedding layer in decoder part so that I did step like this

In def forward, I change from

embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(input)) 

to
embedded = self.dropout(input) 

but I got an error For unbatched 2-D input, hx and cx should also be 2-D but got (3-D, 3-D) tensors

Following that, I ask clude3 that say I should check if hidden and cell are 3D, if so, squeeze the first dimension with code

if hidden.ndim == 3:
    hidden = hidden.squeeze(0)  # hidden = [batch size, hidden dim]
if cell.ndim == 3:
    cell = cell.squeeze(0)  # cell = [batch size, hidden dim]

Until now, it is still error that is the same as I got in step 1)
My question

Could you please help me to solve it and I’m not sure that it have other impacts on another part?

This is my the latest code:
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers, dropout=dropout)
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, input, hidden, cell):
        # input = [batch size]
        # hidden = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hidden dim]
        # cell = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hidden dim]
        # n directions in the decoder will both always be 1, therefore:
        # hidden = [n layers, batch size, hidden dim]
        # context = [n layers, batch size, hidden dim]
        input = input.unsqueeze(0)
        # input = [1, batch size]
        embedded = self.dropout(input)
        # embedded = [1, batch size, embedding dim]
        output, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(embedded, (hidden, cell))
        # output = [seq length, batch size, hidden dim * n directions]
        # hidden = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hidden dim]
        # cell = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hidden dim]
        # seq length and n directions will always be 1 in this decoder, therefore:
        # output = [1, batch size, hidden dim]
        # hidden = [n layers, batch size, hidden dim]
        # cell = [n layers, batch size, hidden dim]
        prediction = self.fc_out(output.squeeze(0))
        # prediction = [batch size, output dim]
        return prediction, hidden, cell

